Android says socket is connected when not even in the same network
I'm having an issue with a specific device (a Samsung Galaxy A54, but one specific one).
I'm trying to connect to a socket, while not in the same network (the ip address isn't even pingable), which I'm expecting to either timeout, or at least throw another exception.
Instead, it just returns, and socket.isConnected even returns true.
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun openSocket(address: InetSocketAddress): Boolean {
        val socket = createSocket()
        return try {
            socket.connect(address, 2500)
            this.socket = socket
            socket.isConnected
        } catch (e: ConnectException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
    }

I've tried this on different devices (including another Galaxy A54), where it does behave as expected.
I've also tried changing
socket.isConnected to socket.isConnected && !socket.isClosed, but it still returns true.

Neither Socket.isConnected() nor Socket.isClosed() does what you think it does. They only tell whether you have connected or closed this socket. They don't (can't) tell you anything about the state of the connection. What you should be returning in the success case is true. Socket.isConnected() cannot have any other value at that point. But the fact that an IP address isn't in the same network and isn't pingable doesn't infallibly imply that you can't connect a TCP socket to it. The evidence here is that you did.

@user207421 That's actually what I did originally.
Now I'm getting around it by starting a timer after the connection, and if I'm not logged in after the timer, I try again with a backup ip address (generally for external connections), but it feels a bit hacky, so I'm not sure I'm entirely happy with it.
